# Java EE Webservice: @AroundInvoke not working

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have a question regarding @AroundInvoke for Java EE Webservices:
I am using this class as Interceptor for a REST Service (it is working):

```
public class AuthenticationInterceptor {

  @AroundInvoke
  public Object invoke(InvocationContext ctx) throws Exception {
    if (ctx != null) {
      // do stuff ...
      return ctx.proceed();
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

}
```

I am now trying to use this class for a Webservice (SOAP) that I implemented. For debugging purposes I created a reduced project, which has only one class:

```
@WebService
@Interceptors(AuthenticationInterceptor.class)
public class HelloWorld {

  @WebMethod
  @Interceptors(AuthenticationInterceptor.class)
  public String sayHello(String name) {
    return "Hello " + (name == null ? "" : name) + " !";
  }

}
```

When I deploy the resulting .war file on my glassfish server (3.1.1), the Webservice is available, but - using remote debugging - the annotated method invoke does not get called (unlike when using my REST service). Programming environment:

- Eclipse
- Maven (dependencies: glassfish-embedded-all, javaee-api, junit)
- Glassfish server 3.1.1

For the record: I also tired to add a beans.xml to the project (although that was not necessary for my REST project) - because of this xml file glassfish throws a:
 Error occurred during deployment: Exception while shutting down application container : java.lang.NullPointerException

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
       http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="all">

       <interceptors>
        <class>com.sjd.simple.AuthenticationInterceptor</class>
       </interceptors>
</beans>
```

(Shouldn't it also work without the beans.xml - like it does with my other project?). Doese anybody know the reason why my the annotated @AroundInvoke method is not called?

Comment: I just wanted to mention, that I was searching around a lot - this site would suggest, that I did everything like it is supposed to:
https://weblogs.java.net/blog/meeraj/archive/2006/01/interceptors_wi.html
or did I overlook something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have resolved this issue myself. From what I researched/gathered on the Internet:

> javax.interceptor.Interceptors may be bound to a simple Web Bean,
>   enterprise Web Bean or EJB 3 style session, singleton or message
>   driven bean using the javax.interceptor.Interceptors annotation, or by
>   using a Web Beans interceptor binding.

This seems to be also true when not using JBoss. The problem was that everytime I added @Stateless to my HelloWorld class, I could not reach the Webservice using the URL I used before adding the @Stateless annotation. Since I saw other examples where @Stateless and @Webservice were used together, I dug a littel bit deeper and came across this bug report:

[@WebService and @Stateless not showing endpoint in GlassFish 4.0 admin console](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20658)

Seems that by using the @Stateless annotation the webservice url changes from:

```
http://localhost:8080/<application_name>/<class_name>Service?wsdl      to
http://localhost:8080/<class_name>Service/<class_name>?wsdl
```

In my example:

```
http://localhost:8080/simple-jax-ws/HelloWorldService?wsdl    [without @Stateless]
http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldService/HelloWorld?wsdl       [with @Stateless]
```

I hope this answer might help someone else as well. I also made a blog post in case someone is searching for the source code I used: [blog post](http://sjplog.blogspot.co.at/2014/07/creating-webservice-using-interceptors.html)